# Set JPanel visible if checkbox is selected

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, visible, jcheckbox

I got two Classes:

1. Panel A
2. Panel B

On Panel A, I got a checkbox, which (if selected) should set Panel B visible. This is what I got so far:

```
public class PanelA extends JPanel {

    public static JCheckBox shopBox;

    public PanelA() {
        setVisible(PanelB.checkBox.isSelected());
    }
}
```

And this is a part of panel B:

```
        checkBox = new JCheckBox("Show PanelA");
        add(checkBox);
        
        checkBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //PanelA.setVisible(virusBox.isSelected());
        }
    });
```

Now this doesn't work. How can I make `JPanelB` visible/invisible regarding the state of the `JCheckBox` on `JPanelA`?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). The 2nd card would be a blank component (e.g. a `JPanel` with no components, or a `JLabel` with no icon / text).

Answer (score -1):

You should repaint the frame

```
 this.repaint();
```

Comment: what does this change?

Comment: it repaints the component, as consequence the component will update and show the new panel

Comment: because the error (nullpointer at line "setVisible(ToolbarPanel.virusBox.isSelected());") is still there